# Python get contents of closed file descriptor

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, file-descriptor

I am writing a bunch of unit tests for a program.  One of the function writes to a certain file descriptor then closes the file descriptor.  I am trying to think of a best way to have a unit test for this specific function, without changing the function in question.

Is there a way to get the contents of the closed file descriptor?  or somehow duplicate that file descriptor, that even if that file descriptor is closed, the duplicate can still read the contents?

Example:

```
def writer(self):
    print("testing only", file=self.some_file_descriptor)
    self.some_file_descriptor.close()
```

The unit test will look something like:

```
def test_writer():
    ...
    a.writer()
    assert fd == "testing only"  ## where fd is the duplicate file descriptor
```

I tried passing sys.stdout as the self.some_file_descriptor but when thats closed then I will get a bunch of `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.` since others will be trying to write on it.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41442904/mock-file-stream-in-python

Comment: I also think you're confusing "file descriptor" with "file object".  These are different things with confusingly similar names.  File descriptors are unix-y things returned by os.open, rathern than the pythony file objects returned by open.

Comment: @FrankYellin Yes, I am using file descriptor with os.fdopen()

Comment: Is it an abomination to your application to reopening the file as readonly and access it normally by the tester module?